# How to store PAT or Class inheritance problem?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-erasure, pats

I will describe the structure with which I am currently working. The project is based on the following PAT:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol ProducerOperationProtocol: NSOperation {

  associatedtype Output
  associatedtype Failure: Error
  associatedtype Condition: OperationCondition
  associatedtype Observer: OperationObserver


  typealias Produced = Result<Output, ProducerOperation<Output, Failure>.Error>

  var produced: Produced? { get }


  var condition: Condition { get }

  var observer: Observer { get }


  func willEnqueue()

  func execute()

  func finish(with produced: Produced)

  func finished(with produced: Produced)


  func produce<O: ProducerOperationProtocol>(new operation: O)


  func recieve(completion: @escaping (Produced) -> Void)
}
```

And two accompanying PATS:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol OperationCondition {

  associatedtype Operation: ProducerOperationProtocol
  associatedtype Failure: Error


  var isMutuallyExclusive: Bool { get }


  func dependency<O: ProducerOperationProtocol>(for operation: Operation) -> O?

  func evaluate(for operation: Operation, completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Failure>) -> Void)
}


@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol OperationObserver {

  associatedtype Operation: ProducerOperationProtocol


  func operationDidStart(_ operation: Operation)

  func operation<NewOperation: ProducerOperationProtocol>(_ operation: Operation, didProduce newOperation: NewOperation)

  func operationDidCancel(_ operation: Operation)

  func operationDidFinish(_ operation: Operation)
}
```

And then comes the big disappointment:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
open class ProducerOperation<Output, Failure: Error>: Operation, ProducerOperationProtocol {

  public typealias Output = Output
  public typealias Failure = Failure

  // ...

  // How to store Condition 
  // var condition: Condition { get } ???

  // ...

  // How to store Observers
  // var observer: Observer { get } ???
}
```

I'll try to explain what's going on here. I have two type-erasure classes:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct AnyOperationCondition<Operation: ProducerOperationProtocol>

@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct AnyOperationObserver<Operation: ProducerOperationProtocol>
```

But they don't help in this case. The class in which I'm going to store them can and will be inherited by other classes. I can't write the following code inside the class:

```
private let _condition: AnyOperationCondition<Self>
open private(set) condition: some OperationCondition { _condition }

private let _observer: AnyOperationObserver<Self>
open private(set) observer: some OperationObserver { _observer }
```

But I still need to store them somehow and specify a specific subclass. I can't make type-erasure for the main class either, because it is inherited from the class and conform PAT.

Again. I need to store conditions and observers inside the class, but I don't know how to do it, because the class can be inherited.

And I can't change the PAT like this, because this way I can't guarantee that the same operation is being passed, and I can't store this operation somewhere or work with closures.

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol OperationObserver {

  func operationDidStart<O: ProducerOperationProtocol>(_ operation: O)

  func operation<O: ProducerOperationProtocol, NewOperation: ProducerOperationProtocol>(_ operation: O, didProduce newOperation: NewOperation)

  func operationDidCancel<O: ProducerOperationProtocol>(_ operation: O)

  func operationDidFinish<O: ProducerOperationProtocol>(_ operation: O)
}
```